# how to get on Dio by passing parameters?

Tags: flutter, dio

I'm using using Dio 3.0.9, I'm trying to get with parameters, it's returning a 404 error, in Insomnia/Postman it works perfectly ... **What is wrong with the code?**

```
Response response = await Dio(
  BaseOptions(headers: <String, String>{'authorization': AUTH}))
                .get($url, queryParameters: {                             
                "category": {"id": 1}});
```

note: when using a url without parameters it works, but when it has parameters it doesn't ...

Comment: I can't make a post. I want to do a get to return only a single category.

Comment: So are you passing JSON data ? or just URL parameters

Comment: I need to pass data through JSON, because the API does not accept parameters directly URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Dio doesnt supports passing JSON data through it when we are using GET request. So
One option to solve your problem is use http package or do this

Go to Dio.dart and make this small change

```
if (data != null &&
["POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"].contains(options.method)) {
```

here remove the whole other part that is `if (data != null ) {`
make it like this.

I have searched about it if you still face difficulty you can go here
[github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/252](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/252)

Hope This would help you : )